# How do I seperate CSV headers and columns in PHP

Tags: php, csv, fopen

I am trying to create a csv with PHP, that separate the the headers and columns.

Currently I am able to create the csv and dump the data, but each row in dumped into one cell.

The result is:
[image]

I expected this:

[image]

Here is my code

```
<?php
// Load the database configuration file 
require_once('db/connect_db.php');

//$time = date('Y-m-d:').preg_replace("/^.*\./i","", microtime(true));
    $time = date('Y-m-d');
    $dteTimetamp = date('Y-m-d');
// Fetch records from database 
    $find = $conn->prepare("SELECT School, SchoolAddress, School_Email, Principle_Name,  Reception_Number,  QuantityFingerPrintScanner, InvoiceNumber from School");
    $find->execute();
    $udonr = "$dteTimetamp" . "Request";
    //$filename = "$udonr.csv";
// Create a file pointer 
    $f = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/testfolder/'.$udonr.'.csv', 'w'); 
 
// Set column headers 
    $header = array('School Name', 'Contact Person', 'Contact Number', 'School Address', 'Number of scanners to deliver', 'Invoice Nuber'); 
    fputcsv($f, $header); 

// Output each row of the data, format line as csv and write to file pointer 
    while($row = $find->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
    $lineData = array($row['School'], $row['Principle_Name'], $row['Reception_Number'], $row['SchoolAddress'], $row['QuantityFingerPrintScanner'], $row['InvoiceNumber']); 
    fputcsv($f, $lineData); 

 
// Set headers to download file rather than displayed 
//header('Content-Type: text/csv'); 
// header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";'); 
 
//output all remaining data on a file pointer 
fpassthru($f); 
} 
//exit;
```

Comment: You should [close](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv) the file.

Comment: This is Excel right? It seems valid CSV, but in Excel you have to open it using "import from document" or something otherwise Excel won't treat the file right. I always use Open office or LibreOffice for CSV files instead of Excel. CSV is a pretty delicate format and Excel just interprets too much automatically causing issues in my experience. Code seems fine, could be a bit more optimized but fine

Comment: Just change CSV separator - in PHP or in Excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@FROSIT is right. Excel is kinda dumb about opening CSV files, especially ones with comma separator (ironically).
Your file looks good but if you need to have it automatically open in Excel (e.i. someone else will need to open it), you might want to find which one is the default separator for Excel and set that in your script.